# Javascript 'NaN' on calculate

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying to make a basic BMI calculator.
But I must be doing something wrong as it displays 'NaN' when I click on calculate.
Any ideas out there?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Height: <input id="h" type="text" name="height"><br>
Weight: <input id="w" type="text" name="weight">
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="bmi"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var h;
var w;
var x=Math.round(w/(h*h));
var demoP=document.getElementById("bmi")
demoP.innerHTML="Your BMI is: " + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `h` and `w` aren't set to anything, they are equal to `undefined`

Comment: Please consider next time giving rep to the original author of the most complete answer to your question, @Pinal in this case.

Comment: Tyblitz, I did - He got a +1 and a green tick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
    var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
    var demoP = document.getElementById("bmi");
    var x;

    //checking are h and w numbers
    if (isNaN(h) || isNaN(w)) {
        x = 'Bad value';
    } else {
        x = Math.round(w/(h*h));
    }

    demoP.innerHTML="Your BMI is: " + x;
}
```

Comment: This surely is the most complete answer until now, with validation. Might add the meaning of NaN and explain why HTML id's are not the same as variables in js to make it perfect.

Answer (score 2):

```
var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
```

Please initialize value of h and w using above code.acknowledge user2110655

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Added

```
var h = document.getElementById("h").value; 

var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
```

Jaavscript:

```
    function myFunction()
    {
        var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
        var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
        if((h!="" && isNaN(h)) && (w!="" && isNaN(w) ){
            var x=Math.round(w/(h*h));
            var demoP=document.getElementById("bmi");
           demoP.innerHTML="Your BMI is: " + x; 
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

some changes:

```
var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick and wonderful friendly help! Much appreciated. This one works a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var h;
var w;
var x=Math.round(w/(h*h));
```

`h` and `w` have not been initialized. hence X is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try these vars :

```
var h = parseInt(document.getElementById('h').value());
var w = parseInt(document.getElementById('w').value());
```